# Can uilabel executes action

Tags: ios

In Instagram in the header view we could see there is the profile image and the username right , so I am thinking how is this possible because the username is a UILabel  how when it's clicked on it sent you the user homepage . Any idea ?

Comment: Well I suppose it doesn't have to be a `UILabel` it could be just a simple `UIButton` but if it is then they would probably be using `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: @Popeye do you know how to pass images from selected row to a UIviewcontroller that contains a tableview in it please

Comment: That's really a different question from what is being asked here, if you ask another question (If you haven't already) and paste the code I will take a look and see what I can come up with

Comment: yes please lol i have the code online can you look in profile you will "Get data from TableView to a UIViewController that contains a TableView ". @Popeye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, check "User Interaction Enabled" in the Attribute Inspector, and add an Action method with it. Make sure you connect the action method to the label

EDIT-

I am showing this in code as i cant post screenshots.

Create a Label `@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;`

Connect the Label in Storyboard.

Create a method, that you want to do when user Taps the label.

```
-(void)showHello{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}
```

Now declare a

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
```

I used tapGesture as I want the action to run when I TAP the label.Declare this Gesture as an Instance Variable

in viewDidLoad alloc and init the gesture and add it to the Label

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showHello)];
    [self.myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];  
}
```

Yup that should do it

Comment: Thanks i am about to try it now

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label to make it clickable.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnLabel:)];
[label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[label addGestureRecognizer:gesture];


-(void)tappedOnLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
   // Perform your action
}
```

Comment: so in the storyboard i will create a new UIViewController ,then in the void method i will just use UIViewController ID to just display right

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you. If you are adding label in the storyboard, create an outlet it and add the tap gesture in the coresponding controller

Comment: After I clicked on the UILabel it should take me to userpage which is an UIViewcontroller right so in the gesture method I will just implement the UIViewcontroller right

Comment: ya.. you can create the view controller there and push or present it

Comment: Anything. if you have a segue from the controller having the label to the userpage, you can programmatically invoke the segue by `performSegue` or alloc init the userpage controller

Comment: i will use storyboard id but thanks again can you vote for my question lol i am trying to have more reputations

Comment: I try to use pushview I got a black screen